# Upgrading From Vista to 7 via remote desktop ONLY

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, remote-desktop, upgrade

OK, so not minding the background (fried graphics card + lazy) I want to upgrade a desktop/household server to Windows 7 from Vista. As the title suggests, I want to do the entire process via remote desktop.

My question is, for anybody with experience upgrading, is there any point in the install where the remote desktop connection service ISN'T running that requires user input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for "unattended install". You create a custom media image with a command file which will provide the Windows installer with the data it would normally prompt for.

Comment: I would add that you need to ensure that RDP is enabled as part of the unattended install. The upgrade disables this even if it was previously enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Not likely. As I recall from my last upgrade, the process at one point reboots and asks you for some very fundamental system-level stuff, including product key. Although I haven't verified it, services such as RDP are very likely NOT to be running during these setup steps.

You should, however, be able to get a cheap $40 video card from Newegg.

Comment: *Sigh*... I know :)